# How long does the Cache in Unity hold objects?

Tags: caching, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am loading Asset Bundles from a Server at runtime with "LoadFromCacheOrDownload()".

I wonder how long the asset bundles are stored there (How long? Still there after restart?).
Should I also save them to the filesystem or is the cache enough?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cached data by default sticks around for [150 days](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Caching-expirationDelay.html) before being deleted because it has been unused. So if you don't clean it before that, it will most likely stick around. Caching behaviour is however dependent on [the cache size](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Caching-maximumAvailableDiskSpace.html) as well, which is 50MiB for the web, and 4GiB for other platforms.

With this in mind it's up to you to decide whether or not the cache (and its behaviour) suffice for you, or if you would be better off storing data yourself as well.